# Как отправить сообщение пользователю через Intercom

Tags: php

У меня задача отправить пользователю сообщение в Intercom-е через API.
В документации прочитал что можно отправить обычную сообщению вот так:

```
$intercom->messages->create([
    "message_type" => "email",
    "subject" => "Plato Quote",
    "body" => "And what, Socrates, is the food of the soul?",
    "from" => [
        "type" => "admin",
        "id" => "814860"
    ],
    "to" => [
        "type" => "user",
        "email" => "socrates@email.com"
    ]
]);
```

У меня есть `email` пользователя и `id` админа.

В моем случае сообщение создано в самом intercom-е. 
https://prnt.sc/pldhaw

А можно intercom-у сказать как-то вот так?:

```
$intercom->messages->create([
    "message_type" => "email",
    "subject" => "Plato Quote",
    "messages_id" => "указав здесь айдишник или что-нибудь который указывает на определенное сообщение",
    "from" => [
        "type" => "admin",
        "id" => "814860"
    ],
    "to" => [
        "type" => "user",
        "email" => "socrates@email.com"
    ]
]);
```

Буду очень благодарен за каждую информацию, спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Решил задачу таким образом:

В другом файле строил контент и рендерив этот файл как обычная вьюшка указал в свойство body. Еще Intercom при отправки этот контент, отчищает все теги от классов и стилей. То есть классы и стили просто удаляются.

Указать определенную айдишник сообщение который в интеркоме, не можем. Так как такое API у intercom-a не существует.